# Working with timeseries data. How to get time until switch in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create the column `secs_to_next_domain` which calculates the amount of seconds until the next domain appears within an IP using pandas?

**Input:**

```
    domain      ip      timestamp
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55
```

**Expected output:**

```
Domain       IP       Time                   secs_to_next_domain 
Google       101      2020-04-01 23:01:41    50,992             
Google       101      2020-04-01 23:01:59    50,974            
Google       101      2020-04-02 12:01:41    4,192               
Facebook     101      2020-04-02 13:11:33    N/A               
Facebook     101      2020-04-02 13:11:35    N/A          
Youtube      103      2020-04-21 13:01:41    47,382            
Youtube      103      2020-04-21 13:11:46    46,777             
Youtube      103      2020-04-22 01:01:01    4,222             
Google       103      2020-04-22 02:11:23    129,590          
Facebook     103      2020-04-23 14:11:13    42               
Youtube      103      2020-04-23 14:11:55    N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` and `cumsum` create the addtional group key , then we need to do `shift` and `reindex` back to get the value sub

```
s = df.domain.ne(df.domain.shift()).cumsum()
out = df.groupby([df.ip,s])['timestamp'].first().groupby(level=0).shift(-1)
df['new'] = df.timestamp.rsub(out.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['ip'],s])).values).dt.total_seconds()
df
Out[199]: 
      domain   ip           timestamp       new
0     Google  101 2020-04-01 23:01:41   50992.0
1     Google  101 2020-04-01 23:01:59   50974.0
2     Google  101 2020-04-02 12:01:41    4192.0
3   Facebook  101 2020-04-02 13:11:33       NaN
4   Facebook  101 2020-04-02 13:11:35       NaN
5    Youtube  103 2020-04-21 13:01:41   47382.0
6    Youtube  103 2020-04-21 13:11:46   46777.0
7    Youtube  103 2020-04-22 01:01:01    4222.0
8     Google  103 2020-04-22 02:11:23  129590.0
9   Facebook  103 2020-04-23 14:11:13      42.0
10   Youtube  103 2020-04-23 14:11:55       NaN
```